# styles are not applied Custom theme is copied to rwd/default

Tags: rwd

I have modified the rwd/default for my custom theme. But I didn't directly modify rwd/default files.I created my own package_name/theme_name and copied the rwd files into it and then modified it in version 1.9.0.1. Now I migrated the theme to magento1.9.2.3. Now I wish to upload my theme in the server but not with my own theme_name/package_name. So I copied only the modified files into rwd/default frontend and changed the package_name=rwd and theme_name=default at the backend. Now the styles are not applying.Can anyone please tell me where I have went wrong. Or is there anything that should be done additionally?

Comment: Have you clean the cache? And what do you mean "the styles not applying"? The theme is loading but the skin folder is the the correct one? By the way Magento is merging cuss and b.s. files. Maybe you disable it first to see which files are missing.

Comment: yea I have done it

Comment: So you change from custom package to rwd. Do you changes also the skin folder back to rwd?

Comment: yea I copied my skin folder into skin of rwd/default

Comment: Again what is missing? Styles or templates? What does the network tab says in Google Chrome. Open developer tools (F12) and click on the tab network. There you find a row with css, js, xhr, doc and so on. Click on css and  check for red rows with 404 and then hover the file to see the path magento is trying to load. That should give you a clue.

Comment: Hey thank you .The mistake was I didnt clear the cache at backend properly.Now it is working. thank you